# Convert FormCollection to JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have:

```
Function SaveAnswers(ByVal collection As FormCollection) As ActionResult

End Funciton
```

And I want to turn collection to JSON, I thought there was a serializer to do this but can't seem to find it?

Answer (score 15):

Serialising a FormCollection object did not work for me, the keys serialized, but the values didn't.

I wanted to use an easy way to 'record' the FormCollection values to reuse in test cases.  For this purpose, I created an extension method:

```
public static string ToJSON(this System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection collection)
{
    var list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (string key in collection.Keys)
    {                
        list.Add(key, collection[key]);
    }
    return new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(list);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is. In c#:

```
return Json(object/array/whatever);
```

It returns a JsonResult, which is an ActionResult, so it "fits" into your function as it exists already.

James